# Smiplebar Scroll not working on nested div in grid css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using simplebar scroll on grid, it is working on all div Parent and child but on child it does not show the scroll. I try with flex also, same result. please help me.

```js
$('.myElements').each(element, new SimpleBar());
```

```css
.parent{
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  display:block;
}
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap:20px;
 
}
.child{
  background:#ddd;
  height:100px!important;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent" data-simplebar>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child" data-simplebar>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="child" data-simplebar>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="child" data-simplebar>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="child" data-simplebar>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/varuns99/pen/OJmLRgP

Comment: `"ReferenceError: element is not defined"` Where does `element` come from?

Comment: The line `$('.myElements').each(element, new SimpleBar());` doesn't make any sense. [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) expects a function as argument. It doesn't expect two arguments.

Comment: I don't see `myElements` set as a class to any of your tags, did you `child` class?

Comment: I add `myElements` in the class but not working

Comment: I think it should on the `.child` class. Anyway, I tried it that way on `codepen` thingy and removed `[0]` as that selects only the first element and I assume you want all the child elements. That caused the scrolls to disappear from the child elements like they have been hidden somehow (which is strange) though you can still scroll.